# is it possible to install sharepoint server without hyper-v

Tags: sharepoint-2010, virtual-machine

Is it possible to run a sharepoint server without hyper-v? I am using visual studio 2010 and cannot create a sharepoint project as i have no sharepoint server. I have discovered that on windows 8, the sharepoint server has to be installed on a virtual machine. I cannot enable hyper-v as i do not have windows pro. Is it possible to enable hyper-v without windows pro or use another VM?
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use VirtualBox (http://virtualbox.org) which is free and spin up a VM and you should be able to access it locally to develop to. You may consider installing Visual Studio on the VM itself to avoid having to configure remote debugging.